# Bootstrap dropdown div from row that spans entire container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap row with n number of 150x150 images.  I have this js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tzachary89/4dnva3p4/

Whenever one of these images is clicked I'm trying to have something that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyLCd.png

So whenever I have an image that is clicked I want a div to show that covers the underlying rows. The div may end up being taller than the one in the picture.

how can I get my dropdown menu to span the entire row and to cover the row beneath it? (without pushing the below row down)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:#8faad8;">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2  col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-5" style="margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;" id="tile1">
      <img src="https://rfclipart.com/image2/thumbnail/3b-3b-f2/head-with-beard-and-hair-Download-Royalty-free-Vector-File-EPS-359793.jpg">
  <div class="container" style="background-color: white;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">asdf</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">asdf</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: make everything position:static apart from your container and then make your image absolute - then it will be positioned relative to the container

Comment: so position:absolute on the image tag?  or the div tag that it is contained in?

also when you say everything, does that mean each bootstrap column div?

Comment: @Pete do you think it is wrong to have the nested containers?

Comment: Nested containers are ok, but be careful if it's bootstrap 4 as browsers like ie and flex sometimes have issues with nested flex containers.  As for the absolute positioning, put that on the element that you want to cover the rows.  The static needs to be on any ancestor between that and the container - absolutely positioned elements are positioned in relation to the first non static ancestor it comes across (static is the default position of all elements in case you wondered)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help @Pete. Here is how it is looking:  https://jsfiddle.net/tzachary89/4onqsnrx/

I just need to pull in the far right edge of my dropdown, any thoughts on that?  I also need a way to point some sort of an arrow up to my selected image. i was thinking about trying some sort of dynamic css overlay